# How to set a Foreign Key to NULL in mysql python

Tags: python, mysql, database

I have two tables: STATE and COUNTY, COUNTY has primary key as State and County combined, and it has State as a Foreign key.

[image]

There are entries in COUNTY table of State which do not exist in the STATE table, so I want to set those foreign key's as null. How should I do it? Is this how I should be doing, by setting foreign key's null?

Comment: Why? You would end up with a county that does not belown to a state? Maybe tell us about what you are trying to achieve, then we might suggest a better way

Answer (score 0):

> There are entries in COUNTY table of State which do not exist in the
> STATE table

If this is the case then the column `State` in the table `County` is **not** a foreign key referencing the column `State` in the table `State`.
If you want to define a column to be a foreign key you must do it like this:

```
ALTER TABLE County ADD CONSTRAINT fk_state FOREIGN KEY (State) REFERENCES State(State);
```

If this foreign key constraint existed you would not have counties with non existing states, because they would be rejected by the constraint.

So, update the table `County`:

```
UPDATE County c
LEFT JOIN State s ON s.State = c.State
SET c.State = NULL
WHERE s.State IS NULL
```

and then add the foreign key constraint so you will not have again non existing states in the table.

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=a14465e398171515aba3c29d61771099).